# SQL - CONCAT with an IF statement returning 1583 error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Is there a limitation with the CONCAT function so that it cannot handle an IF statement?  I have this query, that works if it is not a part of a CONCAT but as soon as I put it inside a CONCAT function it gives this error: **#1583 - Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'**

```
SELECT CONCAT((IF(DAYOFYEAR(`deathdatetr`) and DAYOFYEAR(`birthdatetr`),TO_DAYS(`deathdatetr`) - TO_DAYS(`birthdatetr`),(YEAR(`deathdatetr`) - YEAR(`birthdatetr`)) * 365))/365.25 as totaldays, " years old") from tng_people order by totaldays limit 1;
```

This query should return the oldest person in the database (age in years). The table I am querying contains among other things, birth- and deathdates in the format "1860-07-30".

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Use IIF for inline-IF instead of IF

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are messed up.  You have a column alias in the middle of the expression.  It is not surprising that MySQL is confused, because you seem to be as well.

It is fine to use `if()` where any expression is expected.  I much prefer `CASE` (it is standard), but because you started with `IF()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(IF(DAYOFYEAR(`deathdatetr`) = DAYOFYEAR(`birthdatetr`),
                 TO_DAYS(`deathdatetr`) - TO_DAYS(`birthdatetr`),
                 (YEAR(`deathdatetr`) - YEAR(`birthdatetr`)) * 365)
                ) /365.25, ' years old') as total_years
from tng_people
order by totaldays
limit 1;
```

I have no idea what this logic is supposed to be doing.  It doesn't seem useful, but that is another matter.

If you want the days between to dates:

```
select (to_days(deathdatetr) - to_days(birthdatetr)) as total_days
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Gordon.  You are absolutely correct, I am confused.  I found this query in my genealogy software and have been trying to manipulate it so that it worked in Wordpress, but I am having difficulties getting it to work.

Comment: I took your advice and used the following to calculate the number of days between two dates:
`code`SELECT (to_days(deathdatetr) - to_days(birthdatetr)) as total_days,`lastname`
from tng_people
ORDER BY total_days DESC limit 1;`code`
But as soon as I try to use CONCAT and put the number of days together with lastname, I get an error: #1583 - Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat'

Comment: @user1088537 . . . I'm guessing you still have the `as total_days` in the `CONCAT()`.

Comment: Yes I do.  Is that what is giving me issues with the CONCAT function?

Comment: @user1088537 . . . Most likely, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks to help from @Gordon.  Apparently CONCAT() cannot handle what I THINK is called Aliasing, so once I removed that from the CONCAT() (the "...as total_days"), my query worked fine.

```
SELECT CONCAT ("A", FLOOR((to_days(`deathdatetr`) - to_days(`birthdatetr`))/365.25) ) from tng_people order by (to_days(`deathdatetr`) - to_days(`birthdatetr`)) DESC limit 1
```

Thanks for the help!